# Jenkins Source Management (GIT) ignoring refspec/branch filters

Tags: regex, git, jenkins, version-control, devops

I've two main jenkins environment that works off the same repositories but for different releases. A common design as far as I know. The products have a `beta` and a `release` state and should be deployed accordingly by automated pipelines on the respective jenkins.

Here is an example of the GIT configuration for the `beta` version:
branch: */tags/beta/*
refspec: +refs/tags/beta/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/beta/*
[image: beta configuration]

And here is an example of the GIT configuration for the `release` version:
branch: */tags/release/*
refspec: +refs/tags/release/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/release/*
[image]

Problem is, no matter if a tag with name `beta/v1.0.1` or `release/v1.1.0` is pushed to origin, both the jenkins detect a change and rebuild using simply what seems the `latest` tag, ignoring the filtering.

Now that I'm thinking about it, this could be relevant. This is the Build Trigger section for both of them. The webhook on the repository is set to trigger on Tag Push only. My expectation was that every tag push is sent to jenkins that then evaluate if it match the filters but apparently it's not the case.
[image]

I'm fairly new to jenkins so I guess I've misunderstood how this works and would appreciate some guidance, with examples if you have the time.

Run a tag push to get an example of the logs for both the jenkins:

Beta:

```
11:50:37  > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
11:50:37 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
11:50:37  > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@gitlab.com:[OMITTED].git +refs/tags/beta/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/beta/* # timeout=10
11:50:38  > git rev-parse refs/tags/beta/v1.0.14^{commit} # timeout=10
11:50:38  > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f # timeout=10
11:50:38 Checking out Revision 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f (origin/tags/betav1.0.14, origin/tags/beta/v1.0.14)
11:50:38  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
11:50:38  > git checkout -f 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f # timeout=10
11:50:38 Commit message: "testing"
```

Release:

```
11:50:33  > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
11:50:33 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Gitlab SSH credentials
11:50:33  > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@gitlab.com:[OMITTED].git +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/release/* # timeout=10
11:50:34  > git rev-parse refs/tags/beta/v1.0.14^{commit} # timeout=10
11:50:34  > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f # timeout=10
11:50:34 Checking out Revision 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f (origin/tags/beta/v1.0.14, origin/tags/release/beta/v1.0.14)
11:50:34  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
11:50:34  > git checkout -f 9befbfacfc2254de259203283705133834dcd62f # timeout=10
11:50:34 Commit message: "testing"
```

Jenkins v2.263.1
The GIT Plugin version are as follows:

```
GIT Client Plugin 3.6.0  
GIT Parameter Plugin 0.9.13
GIT Plugin 4.5.2
```

[image: git version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [this issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-32630), and illustrated in [this issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-26842), I would use as branch specifier:

```
:origin/tags/beta/*
# or
:origin/tags/release/*
```

That will force Jenkins to consider changes from `origin`.

As the [OP Claudio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331359/claudio) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900821/jenkins-source-management-git-ignoring-refspec-branch-filters/65953214#comment116673587_65953214), an issue like:

- [JENKINS-58907](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58907?jql=status%20in%20(Untriaged%2C%20Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20%22In%20Review%22%2C%20%22Fix%20Prepared%22%2C%20Verified%2C%20%22Fixed%20but%20Unreleased%22%2C%20%22To%20Do%22)%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22tags%22) ("Wrong tag determined on commit with multiple tags") suggests that Jenkins (Git plugin) uses the first tag after alphabetically sorting them, which is not accurate.
- [JENKINS-64720](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64720) (Git plugin fail to checkout tag) is clearer:

> **The branch parameter of the git pipeline step does not accept a tag name**.
> Many other cases are also not supported with the git pipeline step as described in the online help. The checkout step is the preferred Pipeline step for full access to git.

Comment: Just to be sure I get it, so the issue is that I'm using `*/tags/yadayada/` instead of `:origin/tags/yadayada`? As [this](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-32630?focusedCommentId=247662&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-247662) points out this is a problem because of the `/` being in the regex of the filters. Did I got it right? I'll run some test later in the day, monday at the latest, with this suggestion and update/approve this answer in case it works :) thanks

Comment: @Claudio Yes, that is the idea. The regex would match local references instead of `:xxx` remote references (hence the `:origin/xxx`)

Comment: I just tried but creating a new tag `beta/v1.0.18` still triggered both the jenkins to deploy. I tried even just removing the refspec, in case that was enabling some logic in the plugin that was messing up the workflow but it's still the same behaviour. I can't wrap my head around why this is happening, the filters are clear, already the change from `*/tags` to `:origin/tags` shouldn't have been of importance as it seems like the last part is ignored really (`beta/*` and `release/*`).

Comment: Checking the linked issues from your answer, the problem might be that that suggestion applies to branches and should be also fixed but maybe it's not for tags? I'm just thinking out loud here. Anyway, added version of the git plugin to the question text.

Comment: @Claudio OK, and the version of Jenkins itself?

Comment: Jenkins v2.263.1, adding that to the question as well in a moment

Comment: Checking the Jenkins issue board, seems there are several different issues related to tags that could be explaining this behaviour: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58907?jql=status%20in%20(Untriaged%2C%20Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20%22In%20Review%22%2C%20%22Fix%20Prepared%22%2C%20Verified%2C%20%22Fixed%20but%20Unreleased%22%2C%20%22To%20Do%22)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22tags%22

Comment: This seems the right one. Apparently it's a feature that is not supposed to be there (filtering tags) and there was an issue in one of the last deployment of the plugin in which this information didn't make it to the deployed version. Issue reported 6 days ago, fixed but not deployed yet. I'll have to change strategy on the git-deployments. Bummer. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64720. @VonC please update your answer with a link to the issues for whoever might stumble upon this question and I'll award the bounty anyway for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Claudio Answer updated to include your comments. Good catch.